# What causes saturation in a Bipolar Junction Transistor

Tags: semiconductors

[image]

Given above is a familiar picture of the output characteristics of a Common Emitter Transistor, it is clear that collector current,\$I_c\$ at first increases linearly with Base voltage,\$V_{cb}\$ and then attains saturation.

What is the cause of this phenomena?

Does it have to do something with threshold current?

Also at equilibrium, when no current is flowing through the transistor, is there the presence of depletion layer?

Comment: This question resembles a ransom note.

Comment: More like interrogation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that above graph is wrong, and there is no such phenomenon.  The above diagram shows the set of curves for an FET, but with labeling for BJT.  For BJTs there is no ohmic or 'variable resistor' region at low Vce as shown above.  Google Images finds many, many websites with this mistake.  (There are even a few sites swinging the other way, depicting curves for a BJT but labeled as FETs!)

Instead ask your question about the actual characteristic curves of a BJT:

[image: 2n3094]

So, why does collector current go to zero when collector voltage is zero?   (Heh, you already should know that one.)

Better question: why is there a knee in the curve?  It's because everything stops when the net internal e-fields are gone; when Vce=0.

Also, at the left edge, why doesn't the VI curve at Vce=0 drop straight down, why is it instead tilted like a resistor curve?  *Because it's a resistor curve,* the bulk silicon isn't a superconductor.  (A more idealized model would use zero-ohm silicon, and wouldn't have any tilted ramp at saturation, just a vertical drop at the Y-axis where Vce hits zero volts.)

> when no current is flowing through the transistor, is there the presence of depletion layer?

Yes, a junction maintains a significant depletion layer at zero current.  Until the forward junction voltage approaches ~0.7V (for silicon at 300K,) a PN junction remains turned off, with large depletion region and low average conductivity.

PS

Websites are one thing, but I wonder if any current textbook$$ feature this wrong BJT diagram?

And just for future reference, below is a good diagram for FETs, showing the gate-controlled channel-resistivity effect seen below pinchoff (at low drain voltage:)  Also: your original question does apply to FETS, where there really is an odd threshold effect.  Your question could also be stated as "what does 'pinch-off' mean?"

[image]

Comment: The diagram is for a common-base PNP BJT.

Comment: @wbeaty, the funny thing is, our textbook has the same image and it's tragedic to thing that everyone is learning it.

Comment: When \$I_b\$ is zero then none of this would happen, right?

Comment: Can't imagine myself drawing the same diagram at exam.

Comment: I won't care if I lose marks, I would stand for the truth.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to take you through a different approach. I'm going to consider an npn transistor.

In case of the Common-Base mode, the output characteristics look like this -

[image]

Let us first assume that the BJT is in the active mode. The Base-Emitter junction is forward biased and the Base-Collector junction is reverse biased.

The current due to the forward biased EB junction is given by - [image]

The current due to the reverse biased CB junction is given by - [image]

Clearly these currents are opposite to each other.

Now combining these both, you have - [image]

Here [image] and [image] are reverse saturation currents and typical  value is in the range of pF to nF (almost 0).

Take care that I have written [image] in the equations. Since the CB junction is reverse biased, [image]*>0* and hence [image]*<0*. This makes the second term in the Collector current equation to be negligible and we are only left with the first term - [image].

Now, whenever the BJT is on, be it in the saturation region or the active region, the voltage across the Base-Emitter junction will remain at a constant value of 0.7V. Hence,we get the almost constant curve.

Now suppose we start reducing [image] towards 0. This  makes the second term to appear in the equation as [image] is slowly become less and less negative. Consequently, the magnitude of the current will start falling as you can see in the graph above. For [image]*>0.4V*, the transistor is said to be in saturation and both the junctions are forward biased. The current now decreases steeply for small increase in [image].

> Does it have to do something with threshold current?

There's no such thing as a threshold current for a BJT.

> Also at equilibrium, when no current is flowing through the transistor, is there the presence of depletion layer?

Yes. Wherever junctions are present, depletion regions will always be present. It is the depletion region which is maintaining the equilibrium in case of no current flow.

Answer (score 1):

> Given above is a familiar picture of the output characteristics of a
>   Common Emitter Transistor, it is clear that collector current,Ic at
>   first increases linearly with Base voltage,Vcb and then attains
>   saturation.

No, you have misread the site you found this picture on. Here is the fuller picture: -

[image]

If you want the common emitter characteristic go to [this site](https://www.electrical4u.com/bipolar-junction-transistor-or-bjt-n-p-n-or-p-n-p-transistor/) and look at the relevant picture then ask questions. But bear in mind that site describes the common-base and common-emitter circuits using a PNP transistor hence Vce or Vcb are negative values.

Saturation occurs at low magnitudes of Vce or Vcb for a BJT and is different fundamenatally to the saturation effects of FETs.